# How can we refer to a specific line of a file?

Tags: java, algorithm, file, data-structures, hash

I was reading about algorithmic problem and one was the following:

> Having a file with millions of lines of data, there are 2 lines which
>   are identical. The lines are so long that may not fit in memory. Find
>   the 2 identical lines.

The solution suggested was to read lines in parts and create hashes for each line.
E.g. you build the hash for line 1 by building the hash of part-1 of line 1 (which can be read in memory) and then hash of part-2 of line 1 up to part-N of line 1.
Store the hashes in file or hashtable. For any same hash values compare the lines. If the lines are the same we solved it.

Although I understand this solution in high level, I have no idea how this could be implemented. How can we associate a hash with a specific line in file? Is this language implementation detail?
E.g. in Java how would we address this?

Comment: You can map the hashed values with a line by doing a Map<Long, Integer> so the key is the hash and the value is the line number.

Comment: Just store byte offsets.

Comment: You can create a `List<Long>` I suggest generating 64-bit hashes, or longer to help reduce incorrect duplicates.

Comment: @SLaks:Which API for this?

Comment: @JesusRamos:Do you imply NIO?How am I supposed to count lines without reading them in?

Comment: @Cratylus: The regular file IO (or NIO) APIs (streams).

Comment: @Cratylus: How would you define "counting lines" in terms of basic IO operations? (reading bytes)

Comment: @Cratylus You don't have to read in the entire line into memory to figure out if it's a line you can just check for newline characters and hash smaller sections of the strings. (or instead of lines use offset into the file)

Comment: @SLaks:So with regular I/O I can find the offsets *without* reading-in the lines?

Comment: @Cratylus: It is impossible to read a file without reading a file.

Comment: @JesusRamos:Search for new line char without doing `in.readLine()`?

Comment: @SLaks:But the original problem said that the lines do not fit in memory

Comment: @Cratylus: You don't need to store the entire line at once in order to count newline characters.

Comment: @Cratylus You can read one byte at a time in the file. .read() reads one byte at a time in a BufferedReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer is buy more memory.  The longest string you can have in Java 2 GB and that will fit in machines these days. You can buy 32 GB for less than $200.

---

But to solve the problem, I suggest you

- find the offset of each line.
- find the lines which are the same length (using the difference of offset)
- calculate 64-bit or longer hashes of the lines with the same length.
- for the lines with the same hash, do a byte-by-byte comparison.

Note: if you don't have enough memory to cache the entire file this will take a very long time.  If you have a 32 GB machine and it has a 64 GB file, each pass will take about 20 minutes, and this has multiple passes.

---

> 1)Which API to find the offset?

You count the number of bytes you have read, and that is the offset.

> 2)The real answer is buy more memory Project Managers don't agree on this for real products. Do you have different experience?

I point out to them that I could spend a day which could cost them > $1000 (even if that is not what I get paid) saving $100 of reusable memory if they think that is good use of resources. I let them decide ;)

My 8 year old son has 8 GB in a PC he built as the memory cost me £24.  Yet you are right that there are project mangers who think 8 GB is too much for a professional which is costing them that much per hour!?  I have 16 GB in PC which I don't use to run anything serious because I do my work on machine with 256 GB.  You can buy machines with 2 TB these days which is overkill for most applications. ;)

Comment: 1)Which API to find the offset? 2)`The real answer is buy more memory` Project Managers don't agree on this for real products.Do you have different experience?

Comment: @Cratylus 1) Search for file offset definition [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html). 2) What's your basis to say that a project manager don't agree with that? Isn't the software architect more related with? Also, Peter's answer is based on the reality, or do you plan to work with 4KB of RAM for your program?

Comment: @Cratylus For products the may not agree (if the app is running on thousands of computers) for solutions they will agree (Solution != product: A Solution has one dedicated server and client where the calculation is done)

Comment: I added your questions to my answer.

Comment: Adding 1 GB to one thousand machine is management, not technical or even a financial headache.  This sort of problem suggests one large machine, which is usually easier to approve.

Comment: The problem is suggesting to customers to spend money for more RAM.This may not be acceptable as it increases the "price"

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza:See my previous comment.I personally agree that 8 or 16GB is nothing, but when the management has to tell a customer that he needs to purchase more hardware to run the software they are trying to sell, well they don't want to do it.Do you have other experience?

Comment: @Cratylus you're right with that statement, but it's not applicable for this case. The problem limitation must be that you don't have enough hardware, but taking it to the real world, you have plenty RAM to solve it. Again, I must ask you, are you trying to solve this problem with a hardware that has 4KB of RAM or what?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza:No.As said it is an algorithmic puzzle problem

Comment: @PeterLawrey:What is the link for the offset definition.I know what offset is.Not sure how you use the Java File API to find it

Comment: @Cratylus There is no magic API. You count how many bytes you read and that is the offset.  You don't need an API to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

While i agree the solution is to utilize modern techniques, and leverage how cheap memory is these days, the problem is one meant to exercise the mind and understand how to solve the problem under the given constraints.

The hashing you talked about is rather simple. 
The java solution can leverage a few things under the hood which may obscure whats actually going on so i will explain the solution first, and the java implementation second.

Generic Solution:

Hashing, such as SHA1, MD5, etc. generate an integer by compressing the input. Lets say you can only store the first MB of characters in each line.

- You would iterate over each line, get the first MB of characters, and pass that into the Hashing algorithm(MD5 for example).
- You then map the hash as the key, and a list/array of line numbers as the value.
- After the first pass, any lines with a matching first MB of characters will end up with the same hash, and thus in the same list in the map.
- To prepare for the second pass, you search the map and cull any lists that contain only one line number.
- Then you create a list of line numbers by compiling the line numbers from the remaining entries in the map, these lines will be the only ones checked in the second pass.
- Second pass, you pull the Second MB of characters from each line in your line list, hash them and put them in the map in the same fashion as pass one.
- Iterate over the entries in the map, culling hash entries that only have one line number.
- repeat step two but by incrementing the character block(MB) to coincide with the pass number.
- when you reach a pass where you only have one hash with multiple line numbers, and that hash only has two elements, those lines are the two that are the same.

This is essentially a tree search.

Java Method:
Java has a class called HashMap, which automatically hashes the key. by using a

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>
```

for your master map, all you have to do each call

- map.get(mbBlock).add(lineNumber); of course you should check to see if this is the first time this key has been used so you dont get a null pointer exception.
- after each pass, cull the entries containing only one line.
- reiterate over the remaining lines until you only have two line numbers left

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the first k characters of each line, where k is configurable. Do your hash to find several groups of lines that could have identical lines.
2. Based on the result of the first step, in which you great narrow down the search range, run your algorithm on each smaller groups for the next k characters.
3. The search range is narrowed down dramatically after each round if not in the worst case.

The trick of algorithm is that breaking big problems into small ones and make full use of the results of previous steps.